# Any way to link to object files having the exact same function signature (and same namespace)?

Tags: c++, linker

Scenario:

Have two object files A.o, and B.o. Their corresponding .cpp defined a function called sayHi and they have the same signature. Imagine I want to use both implementations on a project. I am trying to link with both but I get a redefinition error. Is there any way I can (without modifying their source code) use both implementations?

I tried creating shared object with a wrapper of one of the object files but this does not work. I imagine because at the end the symbol table is loaded with the data from B.o and that will collide with A.o even if bundled together into a Wrapper.so

**UPDATE**

I have tried creating shared libraries that I will call test1.so and test2.so. These libraries have a wrapper that wraps the symbols that are colliding. In other words test1 has a wrapper that creates a namespace Wrapper and inside of this namespace I create a function that calls the sayHi function from A.o. I do the same for test2.so using the B.o. When I create the executable using the .so I see that no redefinition error is reported by the linker but when calling the wrapper functions:

```
Wrapper2::sayHi();
Wrapper::sayHi();
```

Both are calling the same symbol. Is there any way to be able to have them call the correct symbol?

I have also tried to load them at run time by doing this and it is working but would like to know if it's possible to link them by doing something like
**g++ helloworld.cpp test1.so test2.so** instead of having to do this:

```
void* libraryHandle = dlopen("./test1.so", RTLD_LAZY);

if (!libraryHandle) {
    std::cerr << "Error loading library: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

// Get the function pointer
typedef void (*WrappedFunction)();
WrappedFunction wrappedFunction = (WrappedFunction)dlsym(libraryHandle, "_ZN8Wrapper27sayHiEv");

if (!wrappedFunction) {
    std::cerr << "Error loading symbol: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
    dlclose(libraryHandle);
    return 1;
}

// Call the wrapped function
wrappedFunction();

// Unload the shared library
dlclose(libraryHandle);

libraryHandle = dlopen("./test2.so", RTLD_LAZY);

if (!libraryHandle) {
    std::cerr << "Error loading library: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

wrappedFunction = (WrappedFunction)dlsym(libraryHandle, "_ZN7Wrapper7sayHiEv");

if (!wrappedFunction) {
    std::cerr << "Error loading symbol: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
    dlclose(libraryHandle);
    return 1;
}

// Call the wrapped function
wrappedFunction();

// Unload the shared library
dlclose(libraryHandle);
```

This way I am getting the expected result.

Comment: Wouldn't this violate the one definition rule?

Comment: _"...One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the __entire program__..."_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule

Comment: Yes exactly it does violate the one definition rule but I wonder what someone could do when facing this situation. Imagine that you receive two blackboxes: two different object files and when linked together they violate the one definition rule. Is there no hope?

Comment: You would never be able to guarantee that the correct fixup was done by the linker.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu linux

Comment: Let's say **A.o** and **B.o** each have a `void foo()`.  In your **main.o** that calls `foo()`, how are you going to distinguish which `foo` gets called?  (The code within **A.o** and **B.o** themselves *have the exact same problem*.)  The solution:  fix the code so they have different names, possibly by putting one or both into their own namespaces.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I am describing @Eljay. I understand that one could modify the cpp and have them exist on their own namespace but my question is about what happens if this code comes from different developers and one does not have access to their cpp.

Comment: Then there is no straightforward way to link the files.  One or both developers will have to change their code and provide a correct object file.  There are extraordinary ways to work with those files (like SoronelHaetir's answer), but then you are going through herculean efforts that will also be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Your shared library approach is the correct one, you just need to make sure the symbol in question isn't visible outside the library

Comment: @Satrofu *"my question is about what happens if this code comes from different developers and one does not have access to their cpp"* -- If you don't have access to the source files, then the format should be `.a` or `.lib`, not `.o` (and I would not describe this as the "code" coming from different developers for the simple reason that you did not get the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create wrapper libraries that provide different names for the colliding symbols (that is, have lib1 provide a wrapper for the first object and lib2 a wrapper for the second). Depending on exact circumstances it may be necessary to make these libraries DLLs/shared objects rather than perform static linking.

Comment: I tried doing this and calling the different sayHi from the wrappers and exposing those like this:

`Wrapper2::sayHi();
Wrapper::sayHi();`


But it seems that at the end both wrappers are using the same symbol because both functions end up printing Test1 (or Test2 depending on the order I link the .so).

Comment: @Satrofu you need to make sure the symbol visibility is set to hidden to prevent this happening

Comment: Thank you @AlanBirtles. Creating the libraries with hidden symbol visibility allows me to compile using the dlls and not to have to load them at runtime.

Comment: Ah, am used to MSVC where only what you explicitly export is visible from a DLL.